# Why does rsyslog fail to start after logrotate?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, rsyslog, logrotate

At midnight, a cronjob initiates logrotate to rotate 4 key log files. These 4 log files are also being sent to a log aggregation server by rsyslog. Despite running the rsyslog logrotate command after each log is rotated, sometimes, the server encounters a "Permission Denied" error that prevents rsyslog from sending the logs belonging to the new files. I cannot figure out why this is happening so unreliably.

Here are the errors reported by rsyslog. Note that they occur only on some dates:

```
Jul 31 00:00:01 hostname rsyslogd[26343]: file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Aug 01 00:00:01 hostname rsyslogd[26343]: file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Aug 02 00:00:04 hostname rsyslogd[26343]: file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/nginx.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Aug 09 00:00:01 hostname rsyslogd[26343]: file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Aug 10 00:00:01 hostname rsyslogd[26343]: file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Aug 10 00:00:01 hostname rsyslogd[26343]: imfile: error with inotify API, ignoring file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log': Permission denied [v8.32.0]
Aug 16 00:00:01 hostname rsyslogd[26343]: file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Aug 16 00:00:02 hostname rsyslogd[26343]: file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Aug 19 00:00:03 hostname rsyslogd[856]: imfile: error with inotify API, ignoring file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log': Permission denied [v8.32.0]
Aug 20 00:00:06 hostname rsyslogd[856]: imfile: error with inotify API, ignoring file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/app.log': Permission denied [v8.32.0]
Aug 30 00:00:01 hostname rsyslogd[856]: file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Sep 03 00:00:01 hostname rsyslogd[856]: imfile: error with inotify API, ignoring file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log': Permission denied [v8.32.0]
Sep 03 00:00:04 hostname rsyslogd[856]: imfile: error with inotify API, ignoring file '/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log': Permission denied [v8.32.0]
```

Logrotate is triggered by a cron job, using the root user. Here is the logrotate config:

```
/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/*.log {
    rotate 365
    daily
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    dateext
    dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
    dateyesterday
    postrotate
        /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
}
```

`/usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate`

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
    systemctl kill -s HUP rsyslog.service
else
    invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
fi
```

I know that the logrotate itself is succeeding, because the logrotate verbose logs indicate that, and I see the rotated log files every day. It seems like rsyslog cannot access the newly create files.

Here are the logrotate logs:

```
Handling 13 logs

rotating pattern: /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/*.log  after 1 days (365 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 0 and egid to 106
considering log /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log
  Now: 2020-10-14 00:00
  Last rotated at 2020-10-13 00:00
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log
  Now: 2020-10-14 00:00
  Last rotated at 2020-10-13 00:00
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/app.log
  Now: 2020-10-14 00:00
  Last rotated at 2020-10-13 00:00
  log needs rotating
considering log /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/nginx.log
  Now: 2020-10-14 00:00
  Last rotated at 2020-10-13 00:00
  log needs rotating
rotating log /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log, log->rotateCount is 365
Converted ' .%Y-%m-%d' -> '.%Y-%m-%d'
dateext suffix '.2020-10-13'
glob pattern '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
renaming /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log to /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log.2020-10-13
creating new /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/celery.log mode = 0644 uid = 102 gid = 106
running postrotate script
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
switching uid to 0 and gid to 106
rotating log /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log, log->rotateCount is 365
Converted ' .%Y-%m-%d' -> '.%Y-%m-%d'
dateext suffix '.2020-10-13'
glob pattern '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
renaming /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log to /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log.2020-10-13
creating new /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/django.log mode = 0644 uid = 102 gid = 106
running postrotate script
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
switching uid to 0 and gid to 106
rotating log /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/app.log, log->rotateCount is 365
Converted ' .%Y-%m-%d' -> '.%Y-%m-%d'
dateext suffix '.2020-10-13'
glob pattern '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
renaming /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/app.log to /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/app.log.2020-10-13
creating new /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/app.log mode = 0644 uid = 102 gid = 106
running postrotate script
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
switching uid to 0 and gid to 106
rotating log /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/nginx.log, log->rotateCount is 365
Converted ' .%Y-%m-%d' -> '.%Y-%m-%d'
dateext suffix '.2020-10-13'
glob pattern '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
renaming /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/nginx.log to /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/nginx.log.2020-10-13
creating new /home/ubuntu/remote_logs/nginx.log mode = 0644 uid = 102 gid = 106
running postrotate script
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
switching uid to 0 and gid to 106
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

What is happening to rsyslog that prevents it from accessing the log files occasionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some of the files don't have permission to be created. You need to add `create 0644 root root` in your config file to give the necessary permission to rotate(modify) the content of the file. 
You can also specify the group name `create 0644 root grouname`. But I will suggest using root

```
/home/ubuntu/remote_logs/*.log {
    rotate 365
    daily
    compress
    missingok
    create 0644 root root
    notifempty
    dateext
    dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
    dateyesterday
    postrotate
        /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
}
```